# Oracle Apex How to change font of text input dynamically

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to change font of given text by user dynamically.

Basically give the user options to convert the text provided to change its font.

That saved text would be used as signature.

So if user enters his name, there should be dropdown/options of all available fonts in which the simple text can eb converted.

User can select a font type and that would be saved as the user's signature.

Is this possible via plugin or any other way?

Apex 20.2/21.1

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, that's a wrong approach.

If table - that is supposed to store that "signature" looks like this:

```
create table person
  (id        number primary key,
   name      varchar2(30)            --> this
  );
```

then "font" doesn't mean anything. It isn't (can't be) stored into the `varchar2` datatype column along with the name.

What to do? Nothing, at least not in Apex. As you'll most probably want to **print** that "signature" on a report, change font for that field in your reporting tool (e.g. Oracle Report Builder).

However, that's just *fake* information. Nobody is actually signed that way. Maybe you'd rather store real signature, scanned and stored as image (e.g. .JPG) into a BLOB column:

```
create table person
  (id        number primary key,
   name      varchar2(30),
   signature blob                    --> this
  );
```

Comment: Ok, so even for printing and saving that signature using a different font isn't possible via apex right?

Comment: If it is possible, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Text doesn't have "fonts". That's a display thing, i.e. HTML. You could pick up the element, serialize it to text (innerHtml, maybe?), then store that in a hidden item, but it's going to look like `<input style=font-family:MyFont>John Smith</input>`. But the fact that the user has entered their name in the input should be enough for it to be an electronic "signature."